# Problem with path of a file to load in a WebView

Tags: java, file, javafx

I am trying to load an html file into a window using java through the following code:

```
    public void showManual (ActionEvent event) {

    File myFile = new File("prueba/index.html");
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setTitle("Manual de ayuda");
    stage.setWidth(500);
    stage.setHeight(600);
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());

    VBox root = new VBox();

    final WebView browser = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();

    ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setContent(browser);
    webEngine.load(myFile.toURI().toString());

    root.getChildren().addAll(scrollPane);
    scene.setRoot(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

}
```

The operating system I use is Windows and what myFile.toURI () returns to me is this, file: / E: /data/project/test/index.html and apparently it is not a valid path. Could someone tell me what to do?

Comment: Have you tried `myFile.toURI().toURL().toString()`?

Comment: Is the HTML file an external file or an embedded resource?

Comment: If I already tried and nothing

Comment: the file is inside the project folder

Comment: I'm working on windows and a file uri with this spaces after the protocol and before the drive letter never occured for me. Is the path correct though? Usually you'd use `Class.getResource()` for resources, but using a file should work too, assuming you've specified the correct path. What does `myFile.exists()` return?

Comment: myFile.exist() return true ,in this case how would you use the other way?